# How to create a grid with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would like to create a grid like this with tick, but I don't know how to draw.[image]

Comment: It's a graph, not a picture.  I would use pgfplots and store all the grid points (x,y) in a table.  The caption can be done using \caption in a ;figure environment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for your suggestion!!!!

Answer (score 2):

As John has mentioned this looks more like a graph. If you want to draw it as a figure, here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass[x11names,svgnames,11pt]{article}                                                                                                                                            
%
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \draw[->] (-5,0) -- (5,0) ;
  \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,8) ;

  \foreach \y in {0,1,2} {
    \foreach \x in {-4,...,4} {
      \draw[fill,red] (\x, \y) circle (1.3pt) ;
    }
  }

  \foreach \y in {3,4} {
    \foreach \x in {-3,...,3} {
      \draw[fill,green!70!black] (\x, \y) circle (1.3pt) ;
    }
  }

  \foreach \y in {5,6,7} {
    \foreach \x in {-2,...,2} {
      \draw[fill, blue!70!black] (\x, \y) circle (1.3pt) ;
    }
  }

  \foreach \x in {-2.5,...,2.5} {
    \node at (\x, 0.3) {$h$} ;
  }

  \foreach \y in {1.5,...,4.5} {
    \node at (0.3, \y) {$k$} ;
  }

\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{The finite difference grid.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The figure looks like this:

[image]

Comment: ¡¡¡¡THANK YOU mas FOR THE TIME YOU HAVE TAKEN WHIT THIS FIGURE, ITS BETTER THAN I WANTED!!!! MY BEST WISHES FOUR YOU

Comment: I'm just curios ... what is function of option `scale=1`? How it influence on diagram?

Comment: @zarko, I put it there to indicate to the OP that the figure can be scaled if needed. Otherwise, it can be ignored.